# Where can I find historical P/E ratios for companies?

Tags: historical-data, price-earnings-ratio

Since the market conditions are down, I am considering on investing a little money in stocks, and holding them long-term.

I would like to see which stocks are 'on sale' and am looking at the P/E ratios to determine this.  However, I don't know where I can find historical P/E ratios for a specific company.

For example,  I see that AAPL is priced at $97.34 today with a P/E of 10.34...however, how do I know if this P/E is high or low in regards to it's historical average?

Comment: If you're willing to work a little you can get all past quarterly and/or yearly reports from Apple and calculate the P/E ratio yourself.

Comment: Are you talking about the US market? The US market is actually near recent highs, it was down somewhat in mid-Feb but it is back up know. Also how do you know is a stock is 'on sale'? A stock is never on sale, it might get underpriced or overpriced at times but it is never on sale. And using P/E won't tell you anything about the value of a stock.

Answer (score 8):

The mathematics site, WolframAlpha, provides such data.

Here is a [link to historic p/e data for Apple](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p%2Fe%20appl).

You can chart other companies simply by typing "p/e *code*" into the search box.  For example, "p/e XOM" will give you historic p/e data for Exxon. A drop-down list box allows you to select a reporting period : 2 years, 5 years, 10 years, all data.  Below the chart you can read the minimum, maximum, and average p/e for the reporting period in addition to the dates on which the minimum and maximum were applicable.

Comment: Thanks this is great. But there are a couple of ticker symbols I can't get to work. For example PEP and KO https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p%2Fe+pep
Does it have to be written differently?

Comment: @Arya Try, for example, "p/e ratio KO".  This appears to work.